# Refresh list numbers in select after deleting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list in a select:

**HTML:**

```
 <select id='products'></select>

 //End result after 3 products added
 |1. Chips|
 |2. Gum  |
 |3. Cable|
 |  ...   |
```

**JQuery:**

```
 var select = document.getElementById('products');
 var opt = document.createElement('option');
 opt.value = document.getElementById('aviProduct').value;
 select.appendChild(opt);
```

When I delete #2 it look like this:

**HTML:**

```
 |1. Chips|
 |3. Cable|
 |  ...   |
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#products option:selected").remove();
```

I want to display the correct order of the numbers. How can I read each option with its value and text and refresh the `select` list?

Comment: You'll need to show some code, without that we have no idea what you're doing to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, version 1.11.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "simply" iterate over the option elements and update their text.  For example (omitting error handling, and assuming consistent text formatting):

```
$("#products option:selected").remove();
var count = 0;
$("#products option").each(function()
    {
    count += 1;
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace(/^\d+\./, '.');
    text = count+text;
    $this.text(text);
    });
```